# Average difference between consecutive data

Tags: average

I have in my head a very simple concept, but it's difficult to search for.  I feel like there must be a function for this in statistics, but I have no idea what to look for.

I have a 1 dimensional data set, a simple column of numbers.  Let's say it's {1, 3, 6, 8, 5}.  I want to find the *absolute* average difference, or step, between each data point.  In this case the differences would be {2, 3, 2, 3}, so the average would be 2.5.

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246097/method-for-determining-the-average-deviation-of-data-values-over-time/1246157#1246157) is after the same data, and I know I can generate a second set of data, then average it.  But is there a statistical function that does this on the data set directly, without having to make an intermediate data set?

Thanks,
Ian

*Edit: Clarification regarding absolute steps*

Comment: I am not sure, just in case: it could be the moving average: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Comment: All you have to do is subtract the 1st term from the last, and then divide by one less than the number of terms. $(11-1)/(5-1)=2.5$.

Comment: Nice approach @GerryMyerson.  Unfortunately I neglected to say I am not interested in -ve values, I want absolute steps.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Then I don't think there's any way to compute $(1/n)\sum_1^n|a_j-a_{j-1}|$ without computing the individual numbers $|a_j-a_{j-1}|$.

Comment: It's not the answer I was looking for, but fair enough.  If you post it as an answer @GerryMyerson, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to compute $${1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j-a_{j-1}|$$ without computing the individual numbers $|a_j-a_{j-1}|$.